# Whats the problem it shows ! Missing number, treated as zero

Tags: tables

[image]

the table not working. What is the best solution.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! It would be much better to copy and paste your code as text. It's easier on the eye, searchable, and we can copy and paste it ourselves to play around with it very easily. Simply paste the code in, highlight it, and hit Ctrl+k, or press the code sample button (the one like {})

Comment: I haven't tested the code (see previous comment) but you use `\multirow{2}` for a column header of one column only, use `\multirow{1}` or don't use `\multirow` at all for these columns

Answer (score 2):

Please always post code as text not an image however you can not redefine the built in `clr` column types, you must use a different name so

```
\newcolumntype{C}...
```

then use `C{2cm}` not `c{2cm}` in your table.